# Maven clean install very slow?

Tags: linux, installation, performance, java, maven

Im currently having a problem that I believe is Maven. For an university project, we are requiered to use intelliJ IDEA, java SDK, Apache Maven and Isis. I tried to follow the tutorial for Isis, creating a project, paste the arquetype on the terminal to build it and the mvn clean install, just as I do that, its starts downloading the dependencies but reallyyy slow, Im taking about 2 hours downloading and still doing it, the other students can install it in 3 minutes, so something is definitely wrong. I tried on linux and windows, but the result is the same, I really dont know what could be causing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Linux and Windows in the same machine and the download speed is the same? Well then it has nothing to do with software or the operating system but with your internet connection.

Comment: I have a decent internet connection, 50mb. And to discard the internet connection, two students did the clean install in my house using wifi, both of them finish the compile in 3 min, So is no the internet connection. Maybe is the hardware? I have an i7 4th gen, 12gb ram, and a geforce 740m.